# convert number from dec to hex and reverse and assign value to an index of char array

Tags: arrays, char, hex, reverse

I've an array output of 5 bytes [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x??].
0x?? needs to be replaced with hex value of an integer n.
So if my dec value is 20, my output array should like this: [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14].

I started off with converting the dec value into hex using the following code:

```
int remainder, quotient, temp;
    int i = 1, j;
    char hexadecimalNumber[2];
    quotient = Num;
    while (quotient != 0) {
        temp = quotient % 16;
        //To convert integer into character
        if (temp < 10)
            temp = temp + 48;
        else
            temp = temp + 55;
        hexadecimalNumber[i++] = temp;
        quotient = quotient / 16;
    }

    for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        printf("%c", hexadecimalNumber[j]);
    }
```

I can print the correct hex value when I print the array in reverse order.
But I'm not sure how to reverse this and assign to output array. 
hexadecimalNumber is itself an array. Can I assign that to output[4] so that my output array looks like [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14]?


**Update**: I tried this and fewer lines of code I get an array with the hex value in correct order:

```
char res[2];
    if (Num <= 0xFF) {
        sprintf(&res[0], "%02x", Num);
    }
```

So res[0] has 1 and res[1] has 4. How do I copy 0x14 into output[4]?

I tried to assign the following things to output[4] but doesn't copy 0x14 into output[4]: *res, &res[0], res.

**Summary**

To clear out any confusions, I've listed the input to program and expected output.
Input: N=20
Output: char output[] = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14] -> This is just hex representation of 0 and 20 not a 2D array...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `snprintf` solve it

The follow `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char output[5][5] = {"0x00", "0x00", "0x00", "0x00", "0x??"};
    int n = 20;

    if (n <= 0xFF)
        snprintf(output[4], sizeof(output[4]), "0x%02X", n);

    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", output[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I said "0x00" in the input I meant the hex representation of 0. Sorry for the confusion. I've no issues with converting 0 to 0x00 but issue is when I'm trying to convert 20 dec to hex 0x14 and assign that to output[4].

Comment: I've already tried sprintf and get an array res where res[0] contains 1 and res[1] contains 4. How am I supposed to updated output[4] with 0x14?

Comment: @amy123 see the line `snprintf(output[4], sizeof(output[4]), "0x%X", n);`

Comment: Sorry missed that. Tried snprintf line. But an error throws up. "Debug Assertion Failed! File: stdio\output.cpp :Expression: buffer_count ==0 || buffer != nullptr". Commented that line and errors disappears!

Comment: @amy123 You should test all my code, or show me all your code.

Comment: This literally is all my code:

void convert(int Num) {
 unsigned __int8 output[5] = { 0 };
 if (Num <= 0xFF) {
   snprintf(output[4], sizeof(output[4]), "0x%X", Num);
  } 
}

Comment: I get a decimal value as input, have to convert it into hex n populate an array of 5 bytes where 5th byte is the hex value!

Comment: @amy123 The line `unsigned __int8 output[5] = { 0 };` should be `unsigned __int8 output[5][5];`

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me. The thing is I'm trying to use an API from a library. I cannot edit this library but can view source files. So the way the library has it in a structure is: unsigned __int8 Num[5]; The value assigned to this is { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff } when input is 255; In my case I've a decimal value and in order for me to use this structure, I've to have the same format!

Comment: @amy123 `0xff == 255`, if `input == 255`, `Num[5] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 255}` ?, if so, just `Num[4] = 255.`